# Invalid URL for Subscription API: Instagram

Tags: api, instagram

I'm attempting to test a real-time Instagram stream using the Subscription API, but am having trouble setting up subscriptions for local testing.

I attempted using `localhost:8080` for the callback_url and editing my /etc/hosts file (redirecting `localhost` to `local.machine.com`)

Eventually, I was able to set up a subscription to my home's IP address to receive callbacks from Instagram.

The IP address was in the form: 
`xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080`

However, this morning, I was trying from a different IP address in the form `xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080` which has continuously led to Instagram returning `400: Bad Request: Invalid URL`

Does anybody have any insight as to what Instagram treats as a valid URL parameter for subscriptions?

Comment: Somewhat similar, I'd like to have a callback to my localhost, but I'm not sure how Instagram would be able to see my machine.

Comment: @Bill - If you can access your localhost:8080 from any other computer, then Instagram can also reach your callback_url as simple as that. As an example, for EC2, public IP is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) for this.

It allows you to set up a tunnel between your local machine and the internet.

With ngrok you can on the command line do like this:

```
ngrok http 8080
```

That will give you a url like this: `http://something.ngrok.io`. In your terminal window you can also inspect all traffic through this tunnel.